# PHP multidimensional array to simple array

Tags: php, arrays

Which method is best practice to turn a multidimensional array

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 11 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 14 ) )`

into a simple array? **edit:** "flattened" array (thanks arxanas for the right word)

`Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 14 )`

I saw some examples but is there an easier way besides foreach loops, implode, or big functions? Surely there must a php function that handles this. Or not..?

Comment: What's the size of the original array?  Are you looking for a version that is optimized for speed or just a simple algorithm?

Comment: This is called "flattening" an array. Searching "flatten array PHP" returns a good deal of possible functions. There is no `array_flatten`, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you want to be able to rebuild the original array from the flattened version?

Comment: @YzmirRamirez the original array is the first one posted. It's always in that format, give or take arrays.

Comment: @YzmirRamirez no, just flattened array

Comment: @arxanas thanks! I was struggling to find a term to define it

Comment: 'Always in that format'...so its always a two element array?  If so then no need to loop over...just `array_merge()` the arrays.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = array();
$newArray = array();

foreach ( $array as $key => $val )
{
    $temp = array_values($val);
    $newArray[] = $temp[0];
}
```

See it here in action: http://viper-7.com/sWfSbD

---

Here you have it in function form:

```
function array_flatten ( $array )
{
    $out = array();

    foreach ( $array as $key => $val )
    {
        $temp = array_values($val);
        $out[] = $temp[0];
    }

    return $out;
}
```

See it here in action: http://viper-7.com/psvYNO

Comment: Ah...we don't need the keys...`array_values()` +1

Comment: @YzmirRamirez - Yes. This is [a *very* simple technique that I always use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163172/codeigniter-generate-simple-array-from-database/11163241#answer-11163241).

Comment: Great answer Joseph! Smart idea using keys

Answer (score 2):

You could use [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to flatten an array.

```
$ret = array(); 
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($var) use (&$ret) { 
  $ret[] = $var; 
}); 
var_dump($ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a multidimensional array that shouldn't be a multidimensional array (has the same keys and values) and it has multiple depths of dimension, you can just use recursion to loop through it and append each item to a new array. Just be sure not to get a headache with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. (It's probably not as "elegant" as xdazz", but it's an alternate without using "use" closure.)  This is how the array might start out like:

**Start**

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'woeid' => string '56413072' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'woeid' => string '56412936' (length=8)
```

Then you might want to have something like this:

**Target**

```
   array (size=2)
      0 => string '56413072' (length=8)
      1 => string '56412936' (length=8)
```

You can use [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

**Code**

```
$woeid = array();
array_walk_recursive($result['results']['Result'], function ($item, $key, $woeid) {
     if ($key == 'woeid') {                                       
           $woeid[] = $item;
     }
}, &$woeid);
```